# Out of memory exception with timer

Tags: java, timer

I have a big problem , I'm using arraylist of object and this object has a timer inside.
 so I'm using say 10 as the timer , so the length of arraylist is 10.

whole timer almost take 80 MB from memory .. and if I used my program for a little time , the program will give me out of memory exception .

because all timer take so much from memory and if I move from one frame to

another frame , the program takes the same amount of memory.

I expected that if I try to cancel all timer or equal the object by null

the memory will be decreased but didn't work.

If the question is not clear please ask in comments.

sorry about my bad English .

note :

this program is simple but the real program is big

my object (edge)  :

```
package operationresearch.pert.input;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.effect.Bloom;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;

public class edge extends HBox {

    private ArrayList<TextField> predecessor;
    private Timer t2 ;
    private TextField duration, activity;

  public edge(boolean haveTime) {
    predecessor = new ArrayList<>();
    activity = new TextField();
    activity.setPrefSize(80, 25);
    activity.setPromptText("Activity");
    if (haveTime) {
        duration = new TextField();
        duration.setPrefSize(85, 25);
        duration.setPromptText("Duration");
    }
    Label depend = new Label("Depend on ");
    depend.setEffect(new Bloom());
    TextField init = new TextField();
    init.setPrefSize(40, 20);
    predecessor.add(init);

    this.setSpacing(5);
    if (haveTime) {
        this.getChildren().addAll(activity, duration, depend, init);
    } else {
        this.getChildren().addAll(activity, depend, init);
    }
    setPadding(new Insets(0, 30, 0, 0));
 predecessorControl();
}

private void predecessorControl() {
     t2= new Timer();
    TimerTask task2 = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            TextField last = predecessor.get(predecessor.size() - 1);
            last.setOnMouseClicked((MouseEvent e) -> {
                if (last == predecessor.get(predecessor.size() - 1)) {
                    TextField newText = new TextField();
                    newText.setPrefSize(50, 20);
                    predecessor.add(newText);
                    getChildren().add(newText);
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < predecessor.size(); i++) {
                    System.out.println(predecessor.size());
                    if (predecessor.get(i).getText().equals("") && i != predecessor.size() - 2 && i != predecessor.size() - 1) {
                        getChildren().remove(predecessor.get(i));
                        predecessor.remove(predecessor.get(i));
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    };
    t2.scheduleAtFixedRate(task2, 100, 100);
}

public ArrayList<TextField> getPredecessor() {
    return predecessor;
}

public void setPredecessor(ArrayList<TextField> predecessor) {
    this.predecessor = predecessor;
}

public TextField getDuration() {
    return duration;
}

public void setDuration(TextField duration) {
    this.duration = duration;
}

public TextField getActivity() {
    return activity;
}

public void setActivity(TextField activity) {
    this.activity = activity;
}

public Timer getT2() {
    return t2;
}

public void setT2(Timer t2) {
    this.t2 = t2;
}
```

}

main :

```
package javaapplication2;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;



    public class TestApp3 extends Application {

        private ArrayList<edge> graph;

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            launch(args);
        }

        @Override 

    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        VBox root = new VBox();
        graph = new ArrayList();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            edge edge = new edge(true);
            graph.add(edge);
            root.getChildren().add(edge);
        }

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setWidth(500);
        stage.setHeight(500);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

[image: the output]

Comment: Why are you trying to describe your code instead of posting it?

Comment: sorry, i'm going to make edit

Comment: @shmosel
now you can see my problem by Watching  process in task manger